# Bootstrap background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap. I was making a theme. But at the bottom of the page, where i added a footer background color at the footer tag, it did not change. And also noticed that the class attribute of the footer tag did not show in the firebug inspect element. What was the problem?? Please help.

```css
.page-footer {
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!---page footer------>
<footer class="text-center page-footer">
  <a class="up-arrow" href="#myPage" data-toggle="tooltip" title="TO TOP">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="#">A-B-C Company</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I tried your exact code in JSFiddle and it works. Could you provide us more information? I guess your problem relies on the `class` not loading up

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

`background: red !important;`

for

`background-color: red !important;`

I don't see any troubles, here's the fiddle with the example working:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2L0539s/)